# Add counter field to all documents using mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I need to add a missing counter field in my documents using the mongoshell (v4).

In JS I would do something like this:

```
const affected = await Data.findMany({ dataId: { $exists: false }}).toArray()
affected.map((d, i) => {
    Data.updateOne({ _id: d._id }, { $set: { dataId: i + 1 }})
})
```

Is it possible to do this directly in the shell?

Comment: [You can use javascript in `mongosh`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/).

Comment: @rickhg12hs As far as I know, this is not possible in v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be done using a single query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {dataId: {$exists: false}}},
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {_id: 1},
      output: {dataId: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
      }}
  }},
  {$merge: {into: "collection"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gauy7pTimtT)

Comment: Is this working on mongodb 4? Right here I am using v6 - which is working...

Comment: `$setWindowFields` is available since mongodb 5.0

Comment: Oh... Is there an alternative, which I can use in v4?

Comment: Not a good one that I'm aware of

Answer (score 0):

It's almost identical.

Mongo shell provides the capability to use JavaScript code directly in the shell.

```
use your_database

const affected = db.data.find({ dataId: { $exists: false }}).toArray()
affected.map((d, i) => { db.data.updateOne({ _id: d._id }, { $set: { dataId: i + 1 }}) })
```